# Every word starts with a Capital in meta description

Tags: css, woocommerce, capitalize

I have a problem with custom field I have added to products in a woocommerce environment. When I add a custom field "authors" with the value "Jan van der Lans". It will display like this: "Jan Van Der Lans".

Is there a way to stop it from capitalizing every word? I tried CSS text-transform:none.

```
.site-main ul.products li.product .product-meta {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
    line-height: 20px;
    max-height: 40px;
    text-transform: none;
}

<div class="product-meta"><span class="product-meta-title">Auteur:</span> Jan Van Der Lans</div>



<ul class="products">

                    <li class="post-442 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_brand-lans-prof-dr-j-m-van-der-jan product_cat-11-tm-20 product_cat-pdf shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-11-tm-20 product-cat-pdf instock">

    <a href="http://www.elephantdevelopment.nl/KSGV/publicaties/2-18-volgelingen-van-de-goeroe/"><img width="500" height="500" src="http://www.elephantdevelopment.nl/KSGV/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/ksgv-2-18-500x500.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="ksgv-2-18" srcset="http://www.elephantdevelopment.nl/KSGV/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/ksgv-2-18-500x500.jpg 500w, http://www.elephantdevelopment.nl/KSGV/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/ksgv-2-18-150x150.jpg 150w, http://www.elephantdevelopment.nl/KSGV/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/ksgv-2-18-45x45.jpg 45w" sizes="(max-width: 500px) 100vw, 500px"><h3>2-18 Volgelingen van de goeroe</h3>

    <span class="price"><span class="amount">€8.50</span></span>
</a><div class="product-meta"><span class="product-meta-title">Auteur:</span> Jan Van Der Lans</div><a rel="nofollow" href="/KSGV/publicaties/?add-to-cart=442" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="442" data-product_sku="" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">In winkelmand</a>
</li>





                </ul>
```

Link to the test environment:  http://www.elephantdevelopment.nl/KSGV/publicaties/

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try to add some code to your question, at least which rules are applying to the element.

Comment: Thanks i will do this

Comment: Well you appear to be applying the right rule there. No way to tell though if it's getting over-qualified by another rule somewhere else though.

Comment: Add the generated html to the question to allow us to see what happens. Add only the <ul> generated part.

Comment: I can't find a CSS property that does this, capitalize every word? Is there any ?

Comment: text-transform: capitalize; does exactly that. What happens if you add !important to text-transform: none; ?

Comment: Apply text transform to the <h3> and <a> element

Comment: Yeah it does capitalize every Letter, or capitalize no letters. But it does not stop from capitalizing every first letter of every Word.

Comment: I tried to add it to the <a> element and <h3> element does not seem to have effect. I have added a link to the demo environment.. Thanks for the quick reply guys

Comment: @Vonwelzen are you sure on the DB those field gets saved not capitalized? Because even if you apply no styles to the name of the author it gets displayed as capitalized so I think the problem is not css related

Comment: @Signo I get the same impression. Most likely a php function altering the string before storing it in the database.

Comment: @Signo You are right. It got it from the PHP code which was used to display the custom field. it was the function .ucwords (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php). Thanks a lot for the help. Do I need to post this answer in a way so other users experiencing the same problem benefit from the research.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Yes you are right, thanks for the help

Comment: @Vonwelzen glad I could help :) yes sure, you can post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got it from the PHP code which was used to display the custom field. it was the function .ucwords (php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php). Thanks a lot for the help.